# Is there a way to send SMS through Gamatronic G4 using a script?

Tags: monitoring, sms

I have a monitoring & contrilling hardware from Gamatronic called [Gamatronic G4](http://www.gamatronic.com/ControlAndManagement.aspx?prod=211).

It is used to monitor servers , UPSs, humidity, temperature, and send alert via SMS.

There is a way to send a manual SMS through it's web interface.

I would like to use the G4's SMS sending capabilities to send software related alerts too.

Is there an API or any other way to pro grammatically send an SMS using the G4?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know G4, but if there is a **web** interface (and no API) you can use the free iMacros for Firefox web browser scripting tool via its [browser command line](http://wiki.imacros.net/iMacros_for_Firefox#Command_Line_Support). You would record a macro that logs in and does the "manual" SMS sending, and log out.

Answer (score 0):

i found how to do it :)

just use: http://yourserverip/sms?number=your_number&text=your_text_massage

and post it with HTML.  don't forget you have a user password popup, i was manage to do it with the following powershell script:

```
$msg = "Hey - sending this from powershell :)"
$number = "+XXXXXXXXXXXX"

$url = "http://XX.XX.XX.XX/sms?number=$number&text=$msg"
$username="admin" 
$password="admin" 

$wshell = New-Object -com WScript.Shell
$wshell.Run("iexplore.exe $url")
Start-Sleep 5
$wshell.sendkeys("$username")
$wshell.sendkeys("{TAB}")
$wshell.sendkeys("$password")
$wshell.sendkeys("{TAB}")
$wshell.sendkeys("{ENTER}")
```